# C# Code - How to count the amount of files ia .7z

Tags: c#, file, count, directory, 7zip

I am searching for a way to open a .7z file and to get the amount/number of zipped content inside there by using C# Code.

```
string[] directoryPaths = Directory.GetDirectories(@"heregoesmypath");

foreach (string dircetory in directoryPaths)
{
   int fileCount = (from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@dircetory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) select file).Count();

   string text = fileCount.ToString() + " Files of: " + "????" + " Files in Directory : " + dircetory;

try
{
   File.AppendAllText(_yourfile, text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
            string[] zippeddirectoryPaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"myresultpath");

            foreach (string exdircetory in zippeddirectoryPaths)
                {

                   // FileInfo info = new FileInfo(exdircetory);
                   // var test = info.Length;
                   // MessageBox.Show(test.ToString() + "Bytes");
                   // var test2 = info.Extension;
                   // MessageBox.Show(test2.ToString() + "Format");}
                   // var test3 = Empty;
                   // here must be a methode, which count my amount of files on the   
                   //  .7z file and save it in var test3
```

That is my code so far... Instead of the last 5 lines bevore i need that methode getting the number of files in a .7z file.

In the manually way you would have a File, you do a right klick go on 7-Zip and klick open.
The 7-Zip UI opens and offers you a button Properties. If you klick on that button, another window opens with shows you the amount/numbers of files and folders.

So at all I do not prefer to do that manually if I have zipped lots of files and folders. I like to get a way in C# to save my result in a var, so that i can use them later in my code to write a logging.

So please give me suggestions or example code to solve that problem.

Comment: Post some code that you have done so far.

Comment: At least make an attempt prior to asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the [7z SDK](http://7-zip.org/sdk.html) to call the 7z functions directly from your home-grown tool.

An alternative would be to use the [7z commandline interface](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm) and evaluate the text output.

**Example call:**

```
7z.exe l Repository.7z > list.txt

...
```

**Example result:**

```
7-Zip 9.22 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2011 Igor Pavlov  2011-04-18

Listing archive: Repository.7z

--
Path = Repository.7z
Type = 7z
Method = LZMA
Solid = +
Blocks = 1
Physical Size = 976726
Headers Size = 22453

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2011-08-31 15:57:36 ....A       663225       954273  Repository\codelists\version 0031\codelists.zip
2010-08-30 18:06:23 ....A        30936               Repository\...\map_ALOCAT_EG4003_Child.xml
2010-10-04 16:38:02 ....A        30936               Repository\...\map_ALOCAT_EG4003_Child.xml
.....
2011-09-09 10:40:14 D....            0            0  Repository\ALOCAT\EDIFACT
2011-09-09 10:56:25 D....            0            0  Repository\ALOCAT
2011-09-09 10:46:13 D....            0            0  Repository
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                             130869837       954273  895 files, 2167 folders
```

Comment: The result looks very well, but it looks like it is not saved in a variable to use it for further code and also you do not post any C# Code...

I also update my question and show you just a little bit of Code I created already.

If you are using C# -Code for that call coud you be so polite to post it and tell me which references you are using?!

Refering to 7z SDK i need to find a good tuorial whick explains how to install and use it in my C# Request. Any suggestions?

Comment: The example output shown above was produced by 7z.exe, the commandline tool delivered with 7-zip. No C# coding involved. The idea is that it might be easier to just call 7z.exe from your program and interprete the output listing. This would save you from installing and comprehending the 7z SDK.